# Groupby id to calculate ratios

Tags: python, pandas, finance

**Objective**

I have this df and take some ratios below. I want to calculate these ratios by each id and datadate and I believe the groupby function is the way to go, however I am not exactly sure. Any help would be super!

**df**

```
     id   datadate    dltt   ceq  ...        pstk     icapt  dlc      sale
1  001004 1975-02-28  3.0  193.0  ...      1.012793     1    0.20    7.367237
2  001004 1975-05-31  4.0  197.0  ...      1.249831     1    0.21    8.982741
3  001004 1975-08-31  5.0  174.0  ...      1.142086     2    0.24    8.115609
4  001004 1975-11-30  8.0  974.0  ...      1.400673     3    0.26    9.944990
5  001005 1975-02-28  3.0  191.0  ...      1.012793     4    0.25    7.367237
6  001005 1975-05-31  3.0  971.0  ...      1.249831     5    0.26    8.982741
7  001005 1975-08-31  2.0  975.0  ...      1.142086     6    0.27    8.115609
8  001005 1975-11-30  1.0  197.0  ...      1.400673     3    0.27    9.944990
9  001006 1975-02-28  3.0  974.0  ...      1.012793     2    0.28    7.367237
10 001006 1975-05-31  4.0  74.0   ...      1.249831     1    0.21    8.982741
11 001006 1975-08-31  5.0  75.0   ...      1.142086     3    0.23    8.115609
12 001006 1975-11-30  5.0  197.0  ...      1.400673     4    0.24    9.944990
```

**Example of ratios**

```
df['capital_ratioa'] = df['dltt']/(df['dltt']+df['ceq']+df['pstk'])
df['equity_invcapa'] = df['ceq']/df['icapt']
df['debt_invcapa'] = df['dltt']/df['icapt']
df['sale_invcapa']=df['sale']/df['icapt']
df['totdebt_invcapa']=(df['dltt']+df['dlc'])/df['icapt']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
df = df.groupby(by=['id'], as_index=False).sum()
df['capital_ratioa'] = df['dltt']/(df['dltt']+df['ceq']+df['pstk'])
df['equity_invcapa'] = df['ceq']/df['icapt']
df['debt_invcapa'] = df['dltt']/df['icapt']
df['sale_invcapa']=df['sale']/df['icapt']
df['totdebt_invcapa']=(df['dltt']+df['dlc'])/df['icapt'] 
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     id  dltt     ceq      pstk  icapt   dlc       sale  capital_ratioa  equity_invcapa  debt_invcapa  sale_invcapa  totdebt_invcapa
0  1004  20.0  1538.0  4.805383      7  0.91  34.410577        0.012797      219.714286      2.857143      4.915797         2.987143
1  1005   9.0  2334.0  4.805383     18  1.05  34.410577        0.003833      129.666667      0.500000      1.911699         0.558333
2  1006  17.0  1320.0  4.805383     10  0.96  34.410577        0.012669      132.000000      1.700000      3.441058         1.796000
```

Comment: I've just edited the question, I'd like it by id and datadate. Simply just make it, 
df = df.groupby(by=[['id', 'datadate']], as_index=False).sum()?

Comment: Yes convert the date using `pd.to_datetime()` and then do that